# Vuetify - Programatically trigger v-text-field animation

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When a v-text-field component is populated with text or focused by the user, an animation triggers to move the label text up and to the left, and the field changes color like so:

[image: left shows no animation, right shows after animation]

I am trying to build a multi-select component using the v-text-field component. The reason I can't use a v-select is that my data-set is nested which is currently unsupported.

Is there a way to programmatically trigger this animation without having to focus the field?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that suits my purposes. There is a prop on the v-text-field component called `persistent-placeholder` which forces the label into the post-animated state when true.